# How can I view shared Google Doc(videos) in Metro style IE

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, google-docs

Since Metro style IE cannot play Flash videos, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use the non-metro or desktop version of IE or use another browser. Otherwise - this is not the right forum to discuss such issues.